# Getting duplications when listing records when using has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables: **Manager**, **Site** and **Visit**.

**Goal**

I would like to be able to create Visits in a way that when I find a valid manager and a valid site I will create a valid visit.

**Problems**

When I tried to do it with a simple **has_many :though** association I got some unexpected results(I haven't been using it too often).

I have set it up this way:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites, through: :visits
  has_many :visits
end 
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managers, through: :visits
  has_many :visits
end 
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :site
end
```

The **first problem** I have is when I find a manager and a site:

```
manager = Manager.find(3)
site = Site.find(5)
```

And I create two visits:

```
Visit.create(manager: manager, site: site)
Visit.create(manager: manager, site: site)
```

I have 2 visits as expected:

```
manager.visits.count #2
site.visits.count #2
```

But I haven't expected and I don't wont 2 sites for manager:

```
manager.sites.count #2
```

I would like manager.sites to return just one site as this manager has visited only one site:/

**Problem 2** is that I can't figure out how to set it up so it works the way I described. I probably need another model but I cant figure it out.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add counter column to `Visit`, and instead of creating new row for each visit you will just use something like `x = Visit.find_or_create_by(~manager, ~site); x.counter.increment; (in schema counter should default to 0)`. Than define `has_many :visits` for each (or scopes), and access like `Manager.visits.where(~search by site).counter` and it will give you total visits counter.

Comment: I need to keep track of visits. For example being able to list all the last month visits. Simple counter wouldn't be enough. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

**uniq** to the rescue.

This is [very undocumented](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq) method. It adds DISTINCT to your SQL SELECT.

Changing both:

```
has_many :managers, through: :visits
has_many :sites, through: :visits
```

to

```
has_many :managers, ->{ uniq }, through: :visits
has_many :sites, ->{ uniq }, through: :visits
```

Gave me behaviour I was looking for!

Another issue I had, which was solved much quicker:

I was was getting duplications when I was listing Managers that visited specific site.

```
Manager.all.joins(:sites).merge(Site.where(site_token: "..."))
```

To fix it I had to add a call to **.distinct** after **.joins(...)**

```
Manager.all.joins(:sites).distinct.merge(Site.where(site_token: "..."))
```